# Invertible composition of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

If both $L:V\rightarrow W$ and $M:W\rightarrow U$ are linear transformations that are invertible, how can you prove that the composition $(M\circ L):V\rightarrow U$ is also invertible.

Comment: By finding an inverse for $M \circ L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composition of two invertible functions is invertible and composition of two linear maps is linear.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that a transformation is invertible $\Leftrightarrow $ its associated matrix is also invertible. Then use the matrix associated to the composition to prove that it is invertible.

Comment: This approach simply doesn't make sense in infinite dimensions, and in the finite case why would you do that? You are taking an easier problem about invertibility of set functions and turning it into invertibility of matrices.

Comment: You're right, I didn't take into account infinite spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $L$ and $M$ are two invertible linear transformations. This means that the standard matrix $[L]$ and $[M]$ are invertible. The composition of two linear transformations is just the product of their standard matrices. Go from there.

Comment: See my comment for Galactus's answer.